# Tooltip displays on hover on Bokeh graph should show on mouse over on tooltip itself also

Tags: python, bokeh

I wrote some python code to display dots on map using bokeh. But now there are some hyperlinks which displays on tooltip when hovered on point.But as this is tooltip I'm not able to click on hyperlinks to navigate to other pages. Is there any chance to do so.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions,HoverTool,CustomJS
import bokeh.plotting as plotting
from bokeh import events
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
import tkinter as tk

screenInfo=tk.Tk()



map_options = GMapOptions(lat=26.366314, lng= 77.016513, map_type="roadmap", zoom=5)


source = ColumnDataSource(df)
TOOLTIPS = """
    <div id="Tooltip">
        
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">@Place</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #966;">@Title<a href="@Link">Click here for more details</a></span>
        </div>
        
    </div>
"""
HoverCallback=CustomJS(code="""

""")
# For GMaps to function, Google requires you obtain and enable an API key:
#
#     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
#
# Replace the value below with your personal API key:
p = gmap(API_key, map_options, title="The Hindu",plot_width=screenInfo.winfo_screenwidth()-100, plot_height=screenInfo.winfo_screenheight()-150)

 

p.circle(x="lat", y="lon", size=15,fill_color="blue",fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)

p.add_tools( HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS,callback=HoverCallback))

plotting.output_file('gmap.html')
show(p)
```

This is the data in df in dataFrame fromat [image]

Comment: Can you post the code of what you've done so far?

Comment: Yes sure. I had done.Please check the code

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to click on the tooltip itself, because the tooltip is always positioned next to the mouse, never under it. Your best bet is to also configure a `TapTool` with an `OpenURL` callback to open the the same URL when the glyph is clicked. Here is a complete example with Bokeh `0.13.0`:

```
from bokeh.models import OpenURL, TapTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

url = "http://www.colors.commutercreative.com/@color/"
tooltips = 'Click the circle to go to:<br /><a href="{url}">{url}</a>'.format(url=url)

p = figure(tooltips=tooltips) # "easy" tooltips requires Bokeh >= 0.13.0

data = dict(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[2, 6, 4], color=['firebrick', 'navy', 'olive'])

r = p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=25, source=data)

# these lines prevent greying out untapped circles, remove them
# to have default selection/non-selection appearance
r.selection_glyph = None
r.nonselection_glyph = None

tap = TapTool(callback=OpenURL(url=url))
p.add_tools(tap)

show(p)
```

Comment: Tap tool will be really a best solution but I will be having several URL's on single point. In that case this will be not in use

Comment: You should have stated that requirement explicitly up front. I don't believe there is anything built in that will provide a solution for that use case. It's possible you could write your own custom extension to satisfy your needs.

Comment: That's a different question/problem, so it should go in a new different SO post.